Azure Function - create a folder and store csv files inside it
I have an azure function that should create a folder inside which it some csv files are written.
These files are processed in further steps and then the files/folder shld be deleted.
  string csvfolderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory.Split("\\bin")[0], "CSVOutput");
  if (!Directory.Exists(csvfolderPath))
  {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(csvfolderPath);
  }
    string folderPath = Path.Combine(csvfolderPath, CompanyName);
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }

This runs without any issue locally.
But when this azure function is deployed, it throws error saying 'could not find the file'
Thanks,
PRI.

Remarks:

First of all, you should never touch bin directory in .NET. It's a special directory that exists only during build process; it has nothing to do with application itself.

Secondly, Azure Function is a serverless platform. You shouldn't rely on the file system.



The easiest way to deal with files is to use a Blob Storage service of a Storage Account. (If you deploy an Azure Function, you already have a Storage Account by design as Azure Function doesn't work without one).

The following code is not specific to Azure Function runtime, you can use it in any .NET application.

Add a NuGet package Azure.Storage.Blobs

Connect to the Blob Storage:
// Replace placeholders with respective values

string connectionString = "<STORAGE ACCOUNT CONNECTION STRING>";
string containerName = "<CONTAINER NAME>";

BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

// Create a container if it doesn't exist
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();


Create a blob:
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("<BLOB NAME>");
string blobContents = "<BLOB DATA>";

await blobClient.UploadAsync(BinaryData.FromString(blobContents));




Links:

Microsoft Learn: .NET / Azure Storage Blobs client library for .NET:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.blobs-readme?view=azure-dotnet

Microsoft Learn: Azure / Storage / Blobs / Upload a blob with .NET:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload


